# jQuery x-editable plugin on dynamic fields?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, input, x-editable

I have made a script which enables adding of dynamic inputs on click of a button and removing unwanted inputs with a corresponding x button. My need is to add the **x-editable** plugin on every newly created dynamic input. I'm using x-editable, in such way, that on a selected option from the x-editable popup, an input from the right side gets a value which corresponds to option selected.

I have made that work with static elements but with dynamic ones I have big problems.
First of all, together with all html structure, classes of all dynamic elements are generated with its **classname + number of dynamic field**. precisely I'm doing this with configured Fieldcount: `var FieldCount = 1;` and then in part where the generation of html code was made you add something like `class="privacy-dynamic'+ FieldCount +'"`. And then the first dynamic element gets the class in html code called `privacy-dynamic2` , second gets `privacy-dynamic3` and so on.

Now, my first conclusion is that I need somehow to add a similar option to x-editable in which I would create a script with same  `+ FieldCount +` so every x-editable pop up would correspond to its 'result input' from left rather than one popup to all dynamically made inputs.

I tried to generate a x-editable script in the same way I generate my html structure and it did not worked. Silly try from me, I know, generating script with script, but I was desperate.

Truly I don't know how it could be solved, I'm a bit of a jquery noob, and I'm lost in it. Can it even be solved somehow?

Here is current situation in which you have the first static field with x-editable working, and dynamic fields with same structure for x-editable but without the script for them: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/QxMs7/

html:

```
<div class="container">    
    <input type="text" class="main_activity" id="main_activity" name="main_activity" placeholder="Main activity">
    <div class="parentToDelegate">
        <a href="#" id="privacy" class="privacy" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-value="1" data-original-title="Select visibility">public</a>
        <input type="text" id="privacy_result" class="privacy_result" value="1"/>     
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="InputsWrapper">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span id="AddMoreBox" class="btn btn-info pull-right"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add More</span>
    </div>
```

script:

```
//x-editable
$('.privacy').editable({
    showbuttons: false,
    unsavedclass: null,
    type: 'select',
    inputclass: 'input-medium privacy-select',
    source: [
        {value: 1, text: 'public'},
        {value: 2, text: 'approved contacts only'},
        {value: 3, text: 'matching contacts'},
        {value: 4, text: 'invisible'}
    ],

});

$(function(){
        $('.parentToDelegate').on('change keyup blur', ".privacy-select", function(){
            $('.privacy_result').val($('.privacy-select').val());
        }).blur();
    });

//dynamic fields
$(document).ready(function() {

var MaxInputs       = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreBox"); //Add button ID

var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

$(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
{
//         if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
//         {
        FieldCount++; //text box added increment
        //add input box
        $(InputsWrapper).append('\
        <div>\
        <input type="text" class="other_activity"\
        name="other_activity" id="other_activity"\
        placeholder="Other activity" style="margin:0px 15px 10px 0px"/>\
        <a href="#" class="removeclass"><i class="icon-remove icon-remove-add"></i></a>\
            <div class="parentToDelegate-dynamic'+ FieldCount +' parent-dynamic">\
                <a href="#" id="privacy-dynamic" class="privacy-dynamic'+ FieldCount +'" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-value="1" data-original-title="Select visibility">public</a>\
                <input type="text" id="privacy-result-dynamic'+ FieldCount +'" name="privacy-result-dynamic'+ FieldCount +'" class="privacy-result-dynamic'+ FieldCount +' privacy_dynamic" value="1"/>\
            </div>\
        </div>');
        x++; //text box increment
//         }
return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    if( x > 1 ) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
            x--; //decrement textbox
    }

            $('.income_count').trigger('change');
            return false;
});

});
```

css:

```
.container{
   padding-top:100px
}

.privacy_result, .privacy_dynamic{
    width: 40px;
}

.main_activity, .other_activity{
    width: 140px;
}

.parentToDelegate{
    display:inline;
}

.icon-remove-add{
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -8px;
}

.parent-dynamic{
    display: inline;
    top: -5px;
    left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Any help or advice is welcome, you can edit my jsfiddle freely and post it back

Comment: have you read about jQuery livequery? [`see here`](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery)

Comment: hm... that looks greaat, but in this case I have 'n' number of dynamic elements, or unlimited number of elements... I'm afraid that this would be a problem, or?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this? I am having a similar problem. It seems that the when you click on the x-editable anchor it makes a request which clears the dynamic fields. Did you experience something similar?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a solution for this that allows the `.editable` to fire off on the first click.

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
    $('.username').editable();
    ... and another other fields you need to apply this too.
});
```

Just apply a `mousemove` event since a user is always going to have to move their mouse to click on the field. This works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work on dynamic fields calling your function like this :

`$(document).on('click', '.xedit',function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).editable(your function here);
});`

Be sure you add the class .xedit to the dynamic fields.

I updated your fiddle to show how this is working: http://jsfiddle.net/javimarcos/m7sj2/

You should remove the id in the dynamic fields (they all have the same id).

Comment: Your fiddle does not work. Your code simply makes it editable at the first click (instead of at pageload) and requires a second click to actually show the input field.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am in the same boat where its only loading the popup after the second click @stef

Answer (score 0):

In this way we can add more x-editable selectbox dynamically

```
> Blockquote
/***
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
$(document).on('click', '.xeditable_option',function (e) {
$(this).editable({source : [{value : '',text : 'Select Option'},
<?php foreach($option_array as $option_list){?>
{value : '<?php echo $option_list['option_id'];?>', text : '<?php echo $option_list['option_name'];?>'  },<?php }?> ]});
});
**/
> Blockquote
```