# Adding a content to script generated with createElement property?

Tags: jquery, createelement

Is it possible to add some script that would generate inside of script tags?

I have a jquery script witch adds `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` to my head but actually I would love to have a script which generates something inside. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() 
   {
        //some script
    });
</script>
```

Current situation: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/rjxEJ/

Script:

```
// Use any event to append the code
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    // Use any selector
    $("head").append(s);
});
```

Comment: `s.text= "$(function(){/*some script*/});";`  http://jsfiddle.net/XWHYp/

Comment: What is your purpose with this generating? (to get rid of a probable better solution)

Comment: I'm trying to solve [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568840/jquery-x-editable-plugin-on-dynamic-fields?noredirect=1#comment25560496_17568840)

with it